# 403 - Permission denied error on Ubuntu 14.04 - apache2

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

This question has been asked many times and I have gone through most of the solutions but still no luck.

I am trying to create a virtual host on a new installation of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS version and for some reason I am getting the following error.

```
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

This is what I have done so far.

1. Created the following virtual host in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/om.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin root@localhost
        ServerName  om.localhost.com
        ServerAlias www.om.localhost.com
        DocumentRoot "/home/jay/Projects/om/public"

        <Directory "/home/jay/Projects/om/public">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
             Order allow,deny
             Allow from all
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

2. enabled the host using the following command

   sudo a2ensite om
3. added an entry to `/etc/hosts`

`127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   Desk-PC-Ubuntu-14-02-LTS
127.0.0.1   om.localhost.com`

4. set the permissions on the project directory using the following commands.

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data om
sudo chmod -R 755 om`

5. Enabled the rewrite module

   `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
6. Restarted apache2

`sudo service apache2 restart`

But still I get the same error.

Can anyone please point out what I am doing wrong?

The project is based on Zend Framework 1.12 and uses the following .htaccess files.

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Have you checked the error log? Shoudn't you set correct permissions on the `public_html` folder, since that is the real document root not the om folder?

Comment: @Cyclone I get following error in the error logs. I also tried setting the permissions on the public_html folder but no luck.  `(13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:51153] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/home/jay/Projects/om') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path` Looking to solve this now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your permissions on your whole file path. Check on the `Projects` folder and make sure it's `755`. It wouldn't hurt giving it the `owner` and `group` of `www-data`. If you have any .htaccess files make sure they are assigned `644` and not `755` as well.

Also you are mixing Apache version directives. It appear you might be running 2.4 since you're using Ubuntu 14.04.  So you need to remove these directives.

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

For 2.4 you only need `Require all granted`.

Also I would add a `DirectoryIndex` directive to make sure it's looking for an index file. If it doesn't recognize one, it will try to list the directory and with indexes off will cause a 403 forbidden error as well. Put this in the vhost in your `Directory` tag after Require all granted.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Also in some cases SELinux it be obnoxious and cause permission issues as well. If all else fails and you have SELinux on, then temporarily disable it to see if it fixes your issues.

```
getenforce
```

That will tell you if it's enforcing or not.

```
setenforce 0
```

This will set it to permissive and then you can test out loading the site. This will be temporary and will not withstand a reboot. However you can make it permenant.

You can use the chcon command to change the security context. For example

```
chcon -R --reference=/home/jay/Projects /home/jay/Projects/om/public
```

As always reload/restart apache for any apache config changes. Hopefully something in here will help solve your 13 Permission Denied issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. It helped. The problem is solved now.